# Are there benchmarks of Java LZO vs. Deflate vs. Gzip available?

Tags: java, compression, lzo

The (very outdated) page for [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) contains a link to a Java implementation.  There is also the vague promise of "New ... Java ... interfaces ... sometime in the near future.", but I believe that has been there for a few years.

This makes me think that the old LZO Java implementation may have been slow.  Are there any benchmarks measuring the performance, as well as its relative performance to other compressors (eg, deflate)?

Comment: Note that there is also a recent new java LZO variant, "lzo-java": https://github.com/Karmasphere/lzo-java which seems like an acceptable conversion. As per benchmark linked-to below, LZO (as all the other lz-derivatives, including Snappy) is indeed faster than Deflate/gzip, with lower compression ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ported the latest minilzo.c to java. Initial version is at http://code.google.com/p/java-compress/. Shortly I will adding java based benchmarks for my port.

regards

mahadevan

Comment: Is this project still active? I did not see much activity since your post.

Answer (score 5):

There's a relatively new project: https://github.com/ning/jvm-compressor-benchmark
which compares deflate, and while LZO is not included, adding driver for it should be easy.